# Add in one array three or more

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an output of nsarray like:

```
2014-12-16 04:55:30.345 Syndasis[17108:7559904] (
  "Hello"
)
2014-12-16 04:55:30.348 Syndasis[17108:7559904] (
"Ciao"
)
2014-12-16 04:55:30.351 Syndasis[17108:7559904] (
"Hola"
)
```

And I don't know how to add to one NSMutableArray. If I make this:

```
NSMutableArray *ns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ns addObject:array];
NSLog(@"%@",ns);
```

The output is:

```
2014-12-16 04:59:04.148 Syndasis[17180:7587364] (
    (
    "Hello"
    )
)
2014-12-16 04:59:04.150 Syndasis[17180:7587364] (
    (
    "Ciao"
    )
)
```

I get the array from:

```
NSMutableArray *track = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *summary = [dct objectForKey:@"tracks"];
for (NSDictionary *tracks in summary) {
     [track addObject:[tracks objectForKey:@"foreign_id"]];
}
NSArray *arrayPR = [track firstObject];

NSMutableArray *ns = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:arrayPR, nil];
NSLog(@"%@",ns);
```

Thanks!

Track response:

```
2014-12-16 05:25:29.895 Syndasis[17505:7776895] (
    "Hi",
    "Hola"
)
2014-12-16 05:25:29.895 Syndasis[17505:7776895] (
   "Ciao"
)
```

I want to make: Make an nsarray from the first string for ever object

```
 2014-12-16 05:25:29.896 Syndasis[17505:7776895] (
    "Hi",
    "Ciao"
  )
```

Comment: Look at the docs for NSMutableArray.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear about your question, from my understanding, I think you are looking for:

```
NSMutableArray *ns = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: firstArray];
[ns addObjectsFromArray: secondArray];
[ns addObjectsFromArray: thirdArray];
```

Comment: Got this error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance I don't know why the array is detected by a string... I added the code!

Comment: @IsaacRodríguez: Probably the values you are passing is not an array, just NSLog them and verify, or put a debug point and check

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *track = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *summary = [dct objectForKey:@"tracks"];
    for (NSDictionary *tracks in summary)
    {
//In tracks dictionary, the object for key 'foreign_id' is a array of strings.
        NSArray* lArray = [tracks objectForKey:@"foreign_id"];
//pick first object from array and add it into mutable array.
        [track addObject:[lArray firstObject]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",track);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer or comment a little, don't just post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more approach for you. It may be helpful.

Lets add all values in `NSMutableString` with one separator between each values.

Then separate each values from this string will gives you an object of array.

See below code:

```
NSMutableString *mString = [NSMutableString new];
for (NSDictionary *tracks in summary) {
    [mString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[tracks objectForKey:@"foreign_id"]]];
}
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[mString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
mString = nil;
```

Comment: @Isaac Rodríguez: Earlier was a typo mistake in code, try this code now.

Answer (score 0):

If `albumLists` is a mutable array of arrays, and you want an array of the the first objects in each subarray, you can use a [KVC Collection Operator](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/):

`NSArray* firstTracks = [albumLists valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.firstObject"];`

Of course, you might have separate arrays album1 & album2 you want to do this for, so you could do this to make the array of arrays and then use the collection operator:

`NSArray* firstTracks = [@[album1, album2] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.firstObject"];`

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY I GOT THE SOLUTION! I POST THE SOLUTION FOR THE PEOPLE WHO HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM.

I got remembering my past of Javascript developer.

```
NSMutableArray *nsarray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *array = [[[dct objectForKey:@"tracks"] firstObject] objectForKey:@"foreign_id"];
[nsarray addObject:array];

int len = nsarray.count;
NSMutableArray *var = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    [var addObject:nsarray[i]];
}
NSLog(@"solution %@",var);
```

Thanks for the help!